# Writing down simple expressions in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I've got expression

```
log(tan(3*pi/8))+cos(3*pi)+1/3*cos(3*pi)^2
```

Task is to get symbolic answer -

```
log(2^(1/2) + 1) - 2/3
```

I've been using

```
sym
```

but it returns 3867816025980321/18014398509481984 instead of symbolic answer that I need. I need someone to explain what I'm doing wrong.
 Also I need some help with translating this expression [image: expression] to "PC language".

Comment: to apply power just write value^power , so in your case it should be (value)^1/4 or `power(value,1/4)`, btw I have no idea what you are trying to ask and achieve , please try to follow this [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sym` is used to create symbolic variables. You were on the right track but left out the `quotation marks`.

1. `sym('log(tan(3*pi/8))+cos(3*pi)+1/3*cos(3*pi)^2')`

> log(2^(1/2) + 1) - 2/3

"4 on the left of the radical sign" represents 4th root of your expression

2. `(1+(sin(3*(2*pi+7)/pi))^2)^(1/4)`

> 1.0035

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: yes, thanks alot. As I understood symbolic answer I need gets returned returned beacause you put expression in quotes?

Comment: You are well come. If this is the answer you were looking for then click on the tick mark?

Comment: @maksem That's right. For details, check this https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.html